# Swift Combine: handle async at subscription level or receive level?

Tags: swift, combine

I wish to observe an ongoing series of values, and process each value as it is received. The act of handling the value may cause a new value to be generated and posted. This is the cause of reentrancy problems.

The original code was written in `RxSwift` and the reentrancy problem was dealt with by the use of an async scheduler:

```
eventSubject
    .asObservable()
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] event in
        self?.handleEvent(event)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I would like to do the same with `Combine`, but am confused as to my options.

```
enum Event { case foo, bar, baz }

@Published var eventFlow: Event = .foo

...

$eventFlow
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .sink { [weak self] event in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.handleEvent(event)
        }
    }
    .store(in: &cancelBag)
```

Q. is this a valid approach? Is the '`receive(on: RunLoop.main)`' required?

And/or should I be subscribing on a queue, such as `DispatchQueue.global()`, and foregoing the `DispatchQueue.main.async` call?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `DispatchQueue.main.async`, simply pass `DispatchQueue.main` to `receive(on:)`, which will make sure all subsequent operators will be executed on the main thread - and hence your `sink` will call back on the main thread as well.

```
$eventFlow
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { [weak self] event in
        self?.handleEvent(event)
    }
    .store(in: &cancelBag)
```

Comment: Thankyou Dávid Pásztor, much appreciated. I will run your solution through tests.